# Unable to upload the subcategories to Woocommerce using WoocommerceAPI

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, backend, categories

I have an issue with uploading categories/subcategories to a woocommerce e-shop using their Woocommerce API. Im using Javascript to get the data from the backend and I don't have any other issue regarding other exports to the site, but when I try to upload a category (I'm getting a list of categories from the backend, which also has a hasSubcategory boolean, id, alias, name), but when I try to upload it to the site, I'm unable to pass the id for the category/subcategory, because it wont upload it. If I leave it without the ids, then I won't be able to set the products to their corresponding category(they include a category_path with the id to the categories/subcategories).
Snippet of the category part: (I have tried so many things around it and deleted all of it so its jsut a short code). P.S: The function is being called! Thanks for any advice!

```
 async function createSubcategories(apiKey, category, WooCommerce) {
   const subCategories = await categories(apiKey, category);

  for (let j = 0; j < subCategories.subcategories.length; j++) {
    const values = subCategories.subcategories[j];

    const subCategoryData = {
       name: values.name,
       *CANT INCLUDE* id: values.id
     };

     await WooCommerce.post("products/categories", subCategoryData);
   }
 }
```

I could add/set the categories without their values, but not exactly how I wanted it and it also jsut didn't make sense (without some values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obtain real parent category id returned by WP API in the callback of `WooCommerce.post` and
use it as the value of `parent` key in your `subCategoryData` object:

```
const WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

const apiKey = "***";
const apiSecret = "***";

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: '<URL>',
  consumerKey: apiKey,
  consumerSecret: apiSecret,
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v3'
});

const categoriesData = [
  { name: "Category 1", id: 1, hasSubcategory: true, subcategories: [ {     name: "Subcategory 1", id: 11 }, { name: "Subcategory 2", id: 12 } ] },
  { name: "Category 2", id: 2, hasSubcategory: false }
 ];


async function createCategories() {
    for (let i = 0; i < categoriesData.length; i++) {
      const category = categoriesData[i];
      const categoryData = {
        name: category.name
      };
      const createdCategory = await WooCommerce.post("products/categories", categoryData, function(err, data, res) {
        err ? console.error(err) : (() => {
          const parsedRes = JSON.parse(res);
          if (category.hasSubcategory) {
            createSubcategories(category, parsedRes.id);
          }
        })();
      });
    }
}
  async function createSubcategories(category, parentCategoryId) {
    for (let j = 0; j < category.subcategories.length; j++) {
      const subCategory = category.subcategories[j];
  
      const subCategoryData = {
        name: subCategory.name,
        parent: parentCategoryId
      };
  
      await WooCommerce.post("products/categories", subCategoryData);
    }
  }
  
  createCategories( WooCommerce);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wanted to also get the id of the created category, but it was unfortunate. I could edit your example and continue with my work, thanks again!